# how to make ValidatorCalloutExtender style?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to flip the popup of the ValidatorCalloutExtender position

i want it to five me the arrow from the right side not from the left side !!

is there a way to handle this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.customCalloutStyle div, .customCalloutStyle td{ border: solid 1px #fff;background-color:#fff;  font-size:14px;color:red; direction:ltr; text-align:right;}
```

this is the answer